# Delete line from csv from specific field if it contains below x number of strings/words

Tags: linux, bash, sed

If I have a csv similar to the following:

```
1999, random strings go here, £50.00, 983903893
1957, Another lacklustre line, £99.00, 3983093
1987, Adventure UK, £83.83, 39939
1945, North Wales is the Adrenaline Capital of Europe, £78.99, 83983
```

How can I delete line where field 2 has 3 or less words. So the output would be:

```
1999, random strings go here, £50.00, 983903893
1945, North Wales is the Adrenaline Capital of Europe, £78.99, 83983
```

I'm tempted to say I would like to use sed because it can change the file in  place witout the need to create a new file.

I know how to refer to the 2nd field and remove individual words or symbols with sed from a csv. For example I could use this to remove a question mark:

```
sed -ri ':b s/^([^,]*,[^,]*)\?/\1 /g; t b'
```

But how do I tell said that I want to remove the entire line if there are three or less words? This is the bit i'm struggling with. Thanks.

EDIT: Here is an actual snippet of the file, please refer to this rather than my original example- it's in the same format but different data which seems to have affected how the suggested sed line in Jean-François Fabre answer processes the data:

```
142106729748,Rocky Horror Book,http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Rocky-Horror-Book-/142106729748,0.99
162189532196,Total Film Issue 10,http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Total-Film-Issue-10-/162189532196,0.75
162189528365,Total Film Issue 9,http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Total-Film-Issue-9-/162189528365,0.99
172328113931,Captain America 163 Silver Age,http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Captain-America-163-Silver-Age-/172328113931,2.5
232069020935,Football Picture Story Monthly,http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Football-Picture-Story-Monthly-/232069020935,0.25
262606117082,The geographical Tradition ,http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/geographical-Tradition-/262606117082,10.0
401182170339,Naruto Official Fanbook,http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Naruto-Official-Fanbook-/401182170339,3.0
```

Comment: Posting new input is more useful if you also post the associated expected output. Also when describing requirements, always focus on the positive - in this case phrase them in terms of what you want to select from the input, not what you want to delete. Makes the requirements clearer and can lead to simpler solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl solution:

```
perl -waF, -i~ -ne 'print if 3 < split " ", $F[1]' -- text.txt
```

- `-w` turns on warnings
- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-a` splits each input line into the @F array
- `-F` tells Perl how to split it, in this case it uses a comma
- `-i` modifies the file in place, `~` will be used as a suffix for the backup

[split](http://p3rl.org/split) in scalar context returns the number of fields.

Comment: This wins, does exactly what I need. Cheers.

Comment: Can i just ask, if the field seperater is a pipe in the file and not a comma, do I just replace both of the commas in the line, or one of them with a pipe?

Comment: @nmh: As described in the bullet list, you need `-F'\|'` to use vertical bar as the separator (backslashed to prevent special meaning in regex, quotes needed because pipe is special for shell). The second comma separates parameters to `split`.

Comment: cool  `perl -waF'\|' -i~ -ne 'print if 3 < split " ", $F[1]' -- text.txt`

Answer (score 3):

sed does it (barely, but does it)

```
sed -r '/^[^,]+, (\w+[, ]){4,}/!d' text.txt
```

small explanation:

- first field is skipped
- `{4,}` matches 4 or more words separated by space or comma (next field)
- the `!d` command does not delete those (delete non-matching ones)
- needs `-r` option or some stuff won't work like `\w`

result:

```
1999, random strings go here, £50.00, 983903893
1945, North Wales is the Adrenaline Capital of Europe, £78.99, 83983
```

(well I had to fix the pound sign by hand actually :))

Edit: better just in case a TAB finds its way in the file (thanks potong)

```
 sed -r '/^[^,]*,([[:space:]]+[^[:space:],]+){4}/!d'
```

Comment: I may have spoke too soon, for some reason when I try it on my actual csv it's returning 3 lines out of 600+ and most of them have more than 4 words!?

Comment: @ Jean-François Fabre Check out the data i've added to my question, for some reason your line of code isn't working with it. Nothing is passing through when the line is executed. I can't see why it would be different than with my original sample data as the csv format is the same (scratches head).

Comment: Perhaps the regexp needs to be loosened (tightened?) a little? `sed -r '/^[^,]*,([[:space:]]+[^[:space:],]+){4}/!d' file` i.e. the first field may not exist or whitespace may not be spaces. Or `,`'s may be escaped? If so you need replace them with something else and then do the test (of course don't forget to reinstate them afterwards!).

Comment: you're right. I'll be more radical: other solutions like perl or awk are more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F ', ' '{split($2, arr, " "); if(length(arr)>=4) print}' file.txt
```

- `split($2, arr, " ")` creates array `arr` by splitting the second field on space
- `if(length(arr)>=4) print` prints the record only if the length of the array is `>=4`

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt                                                          
1999, random strings go here, £50.00, 983903893
1957, Another lacklustre line, £99.00, 3983093
1987, Adventure UK, £83.83, 39939
1945, North Wales is the Adrenaline Capital of Europe, £78.99, 83983

% awk -F ', ' '{split($2, arr, " "); if(length(arr)>=4) print}' file.txt
1999, random strings go here, £50.00, 983903893
1945, North Wales is the Adrenaline Capital of Europe, £78.99, 83983
```

Comment: would be a much better alternative to the `sed` solution if the question was about several fields, more splitting, etc.. so +1

Answer (score 0):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything else you should be using awk:

```
$ awk -F' *, *' 'split($2,t,/ */)>3' file
1999, random strings go here, £50.00, 983903893
1945, North Wales is the Adrenaline Capital of Europe, £78.99, 83983
```